# Running outPutChangeLogFile from liquibase-mave-plugin results in heap space error

Tags: mysql, eclipse, maven-3, liquibase

I'm running outPutChangeLogFile from the liquibase-maven-plugin on eclipse, with the diffTypes option set to data. My DB is relatively large and I keep getting a heap space error. Is there a way to increase the heap for liquibase? I tried increasing the VM and and MAVEN_OPTS and none of them worked.

Comment: How did you do it? Are you sure it worked? Imho the heap is managed by the JVM, so there is no liquibase specific switch...

Comment: i changed the VM arguments for m2e run config,and added "-Xms1025M -Xmx2050M" I'm assuming it worked cause now I got a different error "GC overhead limit exceeded -> [Help 1]"

Comment: that still sounds like there isn't enough heap memory. Did you check the java process and it's memory consumption? does the process really take up to 2GB? Can you enhance this even more and try again? You can also try to start liquibase from commandline alternatively to make sure your memory settings work. I don't know if running liquibase with m2e and maven will spawn liquibase within the same jvm?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue was that liquibase was trying to put the data in one big xml file, adding `<outputChangeLogFile>`
to the pom on the plugin configuration fixed the issue by seperating the inserts into single csv files.